# What is the formal/usual name of this kind of connector?

Tags: connector, components, terminology

I need to buy [connectors like these](https://www.e44.com/composants/composants-actifs/circuits-integres/accessoires/barrettes-circuits-integres/male-double-rangee-coude/connecteur-male-male-double-ci-coude-2-20-contacts-pas-2.54mm-6.1mm-HE14MC2X20.html):

[image]

I don't know how to search for them in the millions of existing connector references.

Could you tell me what their formal name is, or what these are usually called?

Comment: I have been trying to answer this before it's closed, because it is quite clear to me that what you need isn't "where to buy this" but "what is this called, so I can find it in a catalog, whatever the distributor is"
So, it's called a "pin strip", and is typically located in the "headers / wire housings" category. If you search by filtering with the number of pins, the number of rows, the pin spacing (pitch), and then quickly look at the product pictures, you'll find it in a second. "Right angle" is a good keyword to use here, as well.

Comment: I know them as "pin headers". They are extremely common.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pin+headers&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: The top level category under connectors for these is often "rectangular connectors" as well, in case that's helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These connectors are :

- two row
- 0.1" pitch
- breakaway
- through-hole
- right-angle
- headers (sometimes called *pin strips*)
- with male pins.

They belong in a larger family of *rectangular connectors*.

Here's [one example of such a part](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/adam-tech/PH2RA-06-UA/9830568).